# Why doesn't the size of the font change immediately after altering it?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to make an option within the setting that **changes the font size of a label**.

I tried to use properties so that when the user changes the font size in Settings, the result/change will show up immediately. Instead, the change only takes effect when restarting the application. Here is my code for reference.

**example.py**

```
import kivy
from kivy.properties import *
from kivy.uix.settings import SettingsWithSidebar
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.config import ConfigParser
from kivy.app import App

example_config = ConfigParser()
example_config.read("example.ini")


class TitleLabel(Label):
    font_size = ConfigParserProperty(defaultvalue=40, section="style", key="font_size",
                                     config=example_config, rebind=True)


class ExampleApp(App):

    def build(self):
        self.settings_cls = SettingsWithSidebar
        self.use_kivy_settings = False

    def build_config(self, config):
        config.setdefaults(
            "style", {"font_size": 40}
        )

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        settings.add_json_panel("Settings", self.config, "settings.json")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ExampleApp().run()
```

**example.kv**

```
FloatLayout:

    TitleLabel:
    SettingsButton:


<TitleLabel>:
    text: "[color=#30C9E9]ExampleTitleText[/color]"

    markup: True
    font_size: int(root.font_size)
    size_hint: None, None
    size: self.texture_size
    pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.5}

<SettingsButton@Button>:
    text: "Settings"
    size_hint: 0.1, 0.1
    pos_hint: {"right": 0.975, "top": 0.975}
    on_release: app.open_settings()
```

**settings.ini**

```
[
  {
    "type": "numeric",
    "title": "Font Size",
    "desc": "Pick how big you want the font to be.",
    "section": "style",
    "key": "font_size"
  }
]
```

I tried to link the `ConfigParserProperty()` to the `font_size` (in `example.kv` under `<TitleLabel>`). I tried to link the `NumericProperty(example_config.get("style", "font_size"))` to the `font_size` also. Neither worked. I know it has to do something with **properties**, but I do not know how I would set it up.

If you have any idea how to fix this, your help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There exists an example from the kivy team that does exactly that.
I think the important thing therein is the on_config_change method they use to update all modified values - Hope it helps

```
"""
Config Example
==============

This file contains a simple example of how the use the Kivy settings classes in
a real app. It allows the user to change the caption and font_size of the label
and stores these changes.

When the user next runs the programs, their changes are restored.

"""

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.settings import SettingsWithTabbedPanel
from kivy.logger import Logger
from kivy.lang import Builder

# We first define our GUI
kv = '''
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    Button:
        text: 'Configure app (or press F1)'
        on_release: app.open_settings()
    Label:
        id: label
        text: 'Hello'
'''

# This JSON defines entries we want to appear in our App configuration screen
json = '''
[
    {
        "type": "string",
        "title": "Label caption",
        "desc": "Choose the text that appears in the label",
        "section": "My Label",
        "key": "text"
    },
    {
        "type": "numeric",
        "title": "Label font size",
        "desc": "Choose the font size the label",
        "section": "My Label",
        "key": "font_size"
    }
]
'''


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        """
        Build and return the root widget.
        """
        # The line below is optional. You could leave it out or use one of the
        # standard options, such as SettingsWithSidebar, SettingsWithSpinner
        # etc.
        self.settings_cls = MySettingsWithTabbedPanel

        # We apply the saved configuration settings or the defaults
        root = Builder.load_string(kv)
        label = root.ids.label
        label.text = self.config.get('My Label', 'text')
        label.font_size = float(self.config.get('My Label', 'font_size'))
        return root

    def build_config(self, config):
        """
        Set the default values for the configs sections.
        """
        config.setdefaults('My Label', {'text': 'Hello', 'font_size': 20})

    def build_settings(self, settings):
        """
        Add our custom section to the default configuration object.
        """
        # We use the string defined above for our JSON, but it could also be
        # loaded from a file as follows:
        #     settings.add_json_panel('My Label', self.config, 'settings.json')
        settings.add_json_panel('My Label', self.config, data=json)

    def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
        """
        Respond to changes in the configuration.
        """
        Logger.info("main.py: App.on_config_change: {0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(
            config, section, key, value))

        if section == "My Label":
            if key == "text":
                self.root.ids.label.text = value
            elif key == 'font_size':
                self.root.ids.label.font_size = float(value)

    def close_settings(self, settings=None):
        """
        The settings panel has been closed.
        """
        Logger.info("main.py: App.close_settings: {0}".format(settings))
        super(MyApp, self).close_settings(settings)


class MySettingsWithTabbedPanel(SettingsWithTabbedPanel):
    """
    It is not usually necessary to create subclass of a settings panel. There
    are many built-in types that you can use out of the box
    (SettingsWithSidebar, SettingsWithSpinner etc.).

    You would only want to create a Settings subclass like this if you want to
    change the behavior or appearance of an existing Settings class.
    """
    def on_close(self):
        Logger.info("main.py: MySettingsWithTabbedPanel.on_close")

    def on_config_change(self, config, section, key, value):
        Logger.info(
            "main.py: MySettingsWithTabbedPanel.on_config_change: "
            "{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}".format(config, section, key, value))


MyApp().run()
```